# What is the holonomy group of a symplectic manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n}, \omega)$ be a (simply connected if it helps) symplectic manifold which is not Kähler. What can we say about its holonomy with respect to a compatible metric $g_\omega$?

I am thinking of the theorem [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/G-structure#relation_to_special_holonomy), which says that the holonomy of a Riemannian manifold $(M^n, g)$ is contained in (a conjugate of) a group $G \subseteq O(n)$ iff $M$ admits a torsion-free $G$-structure.

I believe that a torsion-free $\mathrm{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$-structure is the same thing as a symplectic form (i.e. an almost-symplectic structure with a closed symplectic form).

However, $\mathrm{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is not one of the Lie groups appearing in the classification of special holonomy groups - does this mean the holonomy group is a proper subgroup of $\mathrm{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$? If so, what is it?

Comment: For starters, $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is not a subgroup of $\text{O}(2n)$.

Comment: Oh wow, good point! I guess the $G$-structure theorem really doesn't apply here. 

Am I correct in saying that if the holonomy, which automatically preserves the given compatible metric $g_\omega$, also preserves the symplectic form $\omega$, then it preserves the almost-complex structure as well and therefore we are in the Kähler situation? 

Does this mean that any non-Kähler symplectic manifold will have holonomy that doesn't preserve the symplectic form?